# How to vertical align this images?

Tags: html, css

I have this website and I can't seem to vertical align the images on listing. 
http://www.ruweplus.ro/echipamente-hidromasaj

I tried this but it doesn't vertically align my image:

```css
.image_wrapper img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Also, I used same code on the parent.

Comment: hi, what happened?? my solution didn't work anymore?? i see you also have removed your comment.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the comment because it wasn't correct anymore. Your answer was not the solution. I thought it worked but I had a tag that was not closed well, and that why it seemed the first time it worked, but it didn't. I resolved it on my own. I tried something else.

Comment: lol glad your figured it out. But let me tell you my solution works just fine. next time examine your code well before asking question here!! we don't want to waste time finding solution for your small mistakes.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Your solution did not work. When I tried your solution I forgot to close the parent div tag you suggested and it worked because of bad coding. After I closed the div tag corectly your solution did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you wrap your image with a div and give it a class name, here i give "test".

```
.test::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%
}
.test img{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also your every element after class "image_wrapper", including "test" class, must have height 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment in "old" CSS <= 2 is really hard. I suggest you use CSS3 [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) instead. Note that this will only work in new browsers though.

The gist of it is really simple:

```
.image_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panx0vng/)

By the way, [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great resource to get you started with flexboxes,

Answer (score 0):

add this Css

```
.image_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

and Remove this Css

```
.image_frame .image_wrapper .mask, .edd_download_image:after {
  /* -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07); */
  /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.07); */
}
```

It will work fine I think

Answer (score 0):

if you also need a solution for older browsers you better use the `display:table-cell` method.
you probably need a wrapping element with `display:table`.

The method is descripted in detail over there: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/ (Section: "Harder: Unknown child")

or in short over there: 
http://daker.me/2014/04/4-css-tricks-for-vertical-alignment.html